# Kendo ui Sort with MVVM

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an mvc page designed with MVVM and it has a kendo grid. The grid has 5 columns. The first 4 columns are sortable but the last column isn't. on page load the page is in view mode and the last column is blank. If I click on Edit but which is outside of the grid - the page mode is changed to edit mode the last column shows the Remove button and Add button.

The issue is when the page is in view mode I click one of the 4 columns to sort the 5th column - Remove and ADD button appear. It should not appear because I am still in view mode. Can someone help, please? Thanks

Comment: Can you show your controller method, model class and razor code ?